# A Simple Login/Authorization system using Dancer and Postgres

Tags: perl, postgresql, dancer

As a newbie to Perl I'm struggling to find a simple way to do this. I've created a very simple table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
username TEXT NOT NULL, 
password TEXT NOT NULL);
```

So far I used a simple login system that has a hard coded username and password that I found online:

```
package Example;
use Dancer ':syntax';

our $VERSION = '0.1';
set session => "Simple";

get '/' => sub {
    # template 'index',{},{layout => 0};
    template 'index';
};

before sub {
    if (! session('user') && request->path_info !~ m{^/login}) {
        var requested_path => request->path_info;
        request->path_info('/login');
    }
};

get '/login' => sub {
    # Display a login page; the original URL they requested is available as
    # vars->{requested_path}, so could be put in a hidden field in the form
    template 'login', { path => vars->{requested_path} }, {layout => 0};
};

post '/login' => sub {
    # Validate the username and password they supplied
    if (params->{user} eq 'user' && params->{pass} eq 'letmein') {
        session user => params->{user};
        redirect params->{path} || '/';
    } else {
        redirect printf 'login failed';
    }
};

get '/logout' => sub {
  session->destroy;
  redirect '/';
};
```

How do I get started with linking the database and then matching what the user inputs with what's in the database? And also when do I implement the hashing of the passwords?  Any tutorials will be greatly appreciated - I've been using metacpan but it's not providing as much detail as I need!

Comment: Have you seen these articles from the Dancer advent calendar? [Authentication for the masses](http://advent.perldancer.org/2014/19) and [New user authentication and authorisation framework](http://advent.perldancer.org/2012/2) (the latter is about [`Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible`](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible), which takes away a lot of the boilerplate).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I have, I'm trying to use the second one but confused about how to implement it. I downloaded the directory and was overwhelmed with all the files and unsure what parts I need!

Comment: You downloaded what directory?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The example one they have in: https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're talking about. If you mean you downloaded the source for `Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Example`, that is an example of how to write your own auth plugin, which you don't need to do because [`Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database) already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible) takes care of a lot of boilerplate code for you. You can get a simple login system up and running without having to write any of your own `/login` routes as follows.

### Configure `Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible`

Install [`Dancer::Plugin::Database`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Database) and [`Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database) and add this to `config.yml`:

```
session: "YAML"

plugins:
  Auth::Extensible:
    realms:
      users:
        provider: 'Database'
        disable_roles: 1
```

### Configure database connection

Configure your database connection in `environments/development.yml` so that you can have different configurations for dev and production. This is what the configuration looks like for MySQL, with the connection credentials (database name, host, username, and password) stored in a separate options file `database.cfg`:

```
plugins:
  Database:
    dsn: 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_file=/path/to/database.cfg'
    dbi_params:
      RaiseError: 1
      AutoCommit: 1
```

For Postgres, you should use a [`.pgpass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file to store your connection credentials. Make sure the file is not world readable. See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980156/176646) for an example. Test that your credentials file works on the command line and that your webserver can read it.

Your existing table appears to conform to the [suggested schema](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database#SUGGESTED-SCHEMA) in the docs, but even if it doesn't, you can adjust the table and column names in the [configuration](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database#CONFIGURATION).

### Lock down your routes

Add the `require_login` keyword to a route you want to protect. A `/login` route will be generated automatically with a basic login form, although you can [create your own](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible#Replacing-the-Default-login-and-login-denied-Routes) if you like.

**lib/MyApp.pm**

```
package MyApp;
use Dancer ':syntax';

use Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => require_login sub {
    template 'index';
};

true;
```

(Yes, that really is all the code you have to write. I told you it takes care of a lot of boilerplate.)

[`Crypt::SaltedHash`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SaltedHash) is used to hash passwords automatically. Note that you should never store plaintext passwords in your database; when you add a user to your database, you should generate a hash of the password and store the hash.

Note that roles are disabled in this example. If you enable roles, you can [do other nifty things](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Extensible#Keywords) like only allow users with the admin role to view admin pages.

Comment: Clearly I couldn't understand how the code could be that simple - thank you so much for this!

Comment: @scz You're welcome. There's a lot of info to digest in the docs, especially if you're new to Perl and Dancer.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way: 
[Dancer::Plugin::Authorize::Credentials::PostgreSQL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Authorize::Credentials::PostgreSQL)

Here is a good write up how to do it properly: http://perlmaven.com/storing-passwords-in-a-an-easy-but-secure-way

```
post '/login' => sub {
    # Validate the username and password they supplied

    if (!params->{user} or !params->{pass}){ 
       redirect printf 'login failed';
    }
    # use your own encryption
    my $auth = auth($login, encrypt($password));
    # login successful
    if ($auth) {
        session user => params->{user};
        redirect params->{path} || '/';
    } else {
        redirect printf 'login failed';
    }
};
```

Regards,
Andras